# Spin-orbit coupling in Siesta

Tags: surfaces, spin-orbit-coupling, siesta

I am going to simulate the electronic structure of the **Au 111 surface including Fe-centered porphyrin** on top. Since the molecule includes Fe, I first did spin-polarized calculations. Using converged parameters, I found a value of ~2 for the spin moment along S_z (`spin moment: S , {S} =    2.11024       0.0       0.0   2.11024`). The freestanding molecule also results in a quite similar spin moment.

To study spin anisotropy, then, I started SOC. Considering stringent MeshCutoff, tolerance in Hamiltonian, and density with a fine kgrid, I found an odd value of S=4.7 for Au surface + Fe_porphyrin
`spin moment: S , {S} =    4.67450  -3.29554  -3.31518  -0.00096`

I had defined the initial DM as below:

```
%block DM.InitSpin
Fe_index  2.0    0.0     0.0
%endblock DM.InitSpin
```

which means that the Fe atom starts with 2 unpaired when the S vector is along Z axes.

A Mulliken charge analysis says the extra spin moment stems from the Au surface. I am struggling with this and therefore, any advice will be highly appreciated! Thanks!

1. Both **SIESTA/4.1-b4** and **Siesta/4.1.5** result in the same S value with a slight difference of hundredth.
2. PPs are blyp and consist of required relativistic effects.
3. Atomic positions were highly optimized.
4. DZP was used for all elements.
   A Gamma-centered `kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack` of 5x5x1 is used while a coarser grid is sufficient for converging the `E_tot` in spin-polarized calculations.
5. VDW-KBM is also applied
6. Tolerance of DM, H, and EDM is ten to the power of -6, -5, and -3, respectively.

Comment: I would highly suggest you first run the calculation with the stable 4.1 release. You are running with a beta release.

Comment: Also, the rest of the input file may be necessary information ;)

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future !!! is there a reason why you're using an old (beta) release?

Comment: @NikeDattani and Zeroth, Thanks for your comment. Following your advice, I redo calls using Siesta4.1.5 and obtained the same results with a slight difference of a few hundredth in the S value.

Comment: @zeroth, thanks, I updated the post with new info of input flags.

Comment: @nickpapior were the recently added input flags useful enough for you to perhaps try and write an answer? I'm just trying to help clear up the unanswered queue! Masoud, have you had any luck with this since October?

Comment: Hmm, no I don't know exactly how this comes about, it could be that the spin is propagated to the Au surface, it would be more helpful to try and reproduce this with other dft codes to see if this is *correct* or whether there is something that should be discussed. @masoud, could you try with the *master* version of siesta? The 4.1.5 spin-orbit coupling is only on-site, not off-site. I don't know if this could help.

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer or the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.